# How to apply Oracle VPD Policy to restrict update some specific columns?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, rdbms, vpd

I have some problems when trying to solve my homework about VPD Policy of Oracle. The question is "MYADMIN account has the right to select and update students' Enroll Information. But he is not allowed to see the Score of the student's Enroll Information as well as update the Score of the student's Enroll Information.

I have done the first task (they are not allowed to see the Score of the student's Enroll Information by using column masking), but when I trying to add the word "update" to statement_type to my code like this, the DBMS notifies errors. I have searched the Internet and realized that column masking can be only used for "Select" statment.

So if I want to apply the Oracle VPD Policy to restrict MYADMIN to update the Score of students' Enroll Information. How can I do that? Will I have to create a session_context view?

Here is my code. Thank you so much

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Question5
(p_schema IN VARCHAR2, p_object IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    user_value VARCHAR2(60);
    user varchar2(60);
BEGIN
    user := SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','session_user');
    user_value:= '(select (SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'',''SESSION_USER'')) from dual)';
    IF(UPPER(user) = 'MYADMIN') THEN
        RETURN 'USER != ''MYADMIN''';
    ELSE
        RETURN 'StudentID = ' || user_value;
    END IF;
END;
/

BEGIN
        DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY(
        object_schema =>'SYSTEM',
        object_name => 'EnrollInformation',
        policy_name => 'Question5_MyAdmin',
        statement_types => 'select, update',
        function_schema => 'sec_mgr',
        policy_function => 'Question5',
        sec_relevant_cols => 'Score',
        sec_relevant_cols_opt => dbms_rls.all_rows,
        update_check => TRUE);
end;
/
```

Comment: Ideally you would create a PL/SQL package API that would execute the update for the user. The API would only accept inputs for the desired columns. The user would then have "select" privileges on the table and "execute" privileges on the package or procedure. Using an API also makes it easier to embed auditing, validations, or various types of error handling than if the user was allowed to execute the "update" command directly. That said, see if this is helpful: https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/virtual-private-databases

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. Wish you have a nice day <3